# How can I apply the changes in runtime?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimFlyertransportationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject JetFlame;
    public bool turnOffOn = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, turnOffOn);

        if (turnOffOn)
        {
            JetFlame.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            JetFlame.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void TurnAllAnimtorsOff(Transform root, bool onOff)
    {
        Animator[] animators = root.GetComponentsInChildren<Animator>();

        foreach (Animator a in animators)
        {
            if (onOff)
            {
                a.enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                a.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want that if in runtime I change the turnOffOn flag state apply the changes in real time in the Update for all Animators and also for the JetFlame.  Now it's only aply the changes in the editor before running the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the function to a public function:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimFlyerTransportationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject JetFlame;
    [SerializeField] private bool startOn = false;

    void Start() {
        SetAnimatorsOn(startOn);
    }

    public void SetAnimatorsOn(bool onOff) {
        Animator[] animators = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Animator>();
        foreach (Animator a in animators) {
            a.enabled = onOff;
        }
        JetFlame.SetActive(onOff);
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private AnimFlyerTransportationController controller;

    void Update() {
        if (someCondition) controller.SetAnimatorsOn(true);
    }
}
```